# Unable to connect to JawsDB instance on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I just created a JawsDB MySQL instance and provisioned it with my app. Performing a `heroku config: get JAWSDB_URL` yields the following string:

```
mysql://(redacted-username):(redacted-password)@h40lg7qyub2umdvb.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/schema
```

When attempting to connect to this database using any database manager GUI, such as MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL using the following parameters:

```
| Key        | Value               |
| ---------- | ------------------- |
| hostname   | h40lg7qyub2umdvb.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com |
| port       | 3306                |
| username   | (redacted-username) |
| password   | (redacted-password) |
| connection | TCP/IP              |
```

...I receive the following error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at h40lg7qyub2umdvb.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 with user (redacted-username)

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

This is my second attempt at trying this - I received the same error with the JawsDB instance I just set up earlier, so I deleted that and receive the same error again here. Any ideas?

Comment: Had no idea about how to use the url to connect to heorku jaws. your post helped me a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further investigation, I found out that port 3306 was blocked at my University, no thanks to the unhelpful error message.

Hopefully this helps others who encounter this problem, as this isn't in the docs.

Comment: do you just change the port number in the connection? I am having this same issue

Comment: I was unable to change the MySQL port number in Heroku; if you want more flexibility, you can look into using Amazon AWS instead to host your MySQL instance so you can modify the port number. After talking to the sys admins at my school, if I connect to the private wifi network using my login credentials rather than the public one, it allowed port 3306 through. You may have a talk with your sys admins to see what the rules are or if they can allow it in your case.